# How do I test methods declared in non-public superclass using Mockito? If that's not possible, what are some alternatives?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am currently trying to mock a TypeReference object which extends AbstractNode in this method:

```
private TypeReference mockTypeReference() {
    TypeReference mockTypeReference = Mockito.mock(TypeReference.class);
    Node modifiers = mockModifier();
    when(mockTypeReference.getParent()).thenReturn(modifiers);
    return mockTypeReference;
}
```

The issue is, I get this exception here:

```
   org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

because of this: `Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.`

Here's the declaration for AbstractNode:

```
abstract class AbstractNode implements Node {
```

How do I get around this issue? Is there any way to use mockito successfully here?

Comment: Can you give the instruction where your have the problem ?

Comment: Is TypeReference a class that you wrote? The only two TypeReference classes that I can find are android.hardware.camera2.utils.TypeReference and org.objectweb.asm.TypeReference, both of which do not extend AbstractNode. If it is a custom class, make sure that you're not pulling in one of the above versions by mistake.

Comment: The package is lombok.ast for TypeReference. The line the problem occurs at is this one: when(mockTypeReference.getParent()).thenReturn(modifiers);

Comment: I think this issue is fixed by https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/171, which appears to be slated for Mockito 2.0. They have 2.0.103-beta available, so you may try upgrading to that (https://bintray.com/szczepiq/maven/mockito/2.0.103-beta). Not sure if that is acceptable though since it is still in beta.

Comment: Just kidding, the beta works!